# MatrixAnimationUsingPath animate on surroundings (outline) of path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, pathgeometry

i have a path data that i coppy it from syncfusion program.
i have a path with that data in my page and want to animate my object exact on path way (in mid of path line) but the problem is the object move on outline (surroundings ) of path .

here is code :

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="False" Margin="435,58,279,445" Width="70" Height="70">
                <Path Name="pp" Data="M29.073618888855,0C29.1124091148376,1.1444091796875E-05 29.1515617370605,0.00176620483398438 29.1909990310669,0.00532913208007813 29.810998916626,0.0533294677734375 30.3119988441467,0.530315399169922 30.3919982910156,1.14829635620117L30.5836410522461,2.65130615234375 31.2817029953003,8.12605285644531 34.8569983541965,36.1663000583649 38.6119983196259,11.4410037994385C38.6989989280701,10.8670196533203 39.1539988517761,10.4180335998535 39.7279987335205,10.3390350341797 40.3039989471436,10.2600383758545 40.8659987449646,10.5700283050537 41.1039986610413,11.0990142822266L44.5239992141724,18.6847972869873 62.6889991760254,18.6847972869873C63.4129981994629,18.6847972869873 63.9999980926514,19.2727813720703 63.9999980926514,19.9957599639893 63.9999980926514,20.720739364624 63.4129981994629,21.3077239990234 62.6889991760254,21.3077239990234L43.6779985427856,21.3077239990234C43.1629986763,21.3077239990234,42.6949987411499,21.004732131958,42.4809985160828,20.5357456207275L40.5379986763,16.2248687744141 36.0409992933273,45.8410243988037C35.9439988136292,46.4820065498352,35.3929988443851,46.9559931755066,34.7459992468357,46.9559926986694L34.729998499155,46.9559926986694C34.0749988555908,46.9479932785034,33.5279988050461,46.4590072631836,33.4449987411499,45.8100252151489L28.5969982147217,7.7971076965332 19.7799987792969,38.5482323169708C19.6119985580444,39.1362158469856 19.0699996948242,39.5222048461437 18.4459991455078,39.4962055683136 17.8359985351563,39.4622065722942 17.3289985656738,39.0092194601893 17.2269992828369,38.4062369465828L13.6579990386963,17.2688388824463 10.7719993591309,23.3446655273438C10.5559997558594,23.8016519546509,10.0949993133545,24.0936441421509,9.58799934387207,24.0936441421509L1.31099700927734,24.0936441421509C0.587997436523438,24.0936441421509 0,23.5056610107422 0,22.7826805114746 0,22.0577011108398 0.587997436523438,21.4717178344727 1.31099700927734,21.4717178344727L8.75799942016602,21.4717178344727 13.0749988555908,12.3859767913818C13.3199996948242,11.8689918518066 13.8699989318848,11.57200050354 14.4389991760254,11.6499977111816 15.0059986114502,11.7299957275391 15.4579982757568,12.1669826507568 15.5519981384277,12.7309665679932L18.8509979248047,32.2744116783142 27.8319988250732,0.952301025390625C27.9913740158081,0.391693115234375,28.4917645454407,-0.000171661376953125,29.073618888855,0z" 
                  Stretch="Uniform" Fill="White" Width="70" Height="70" StrokeThickness="0" />
                    <Rectangle Fill="#FFFF4600"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="4" Height="4" Canvas.Top="4">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <MatrixTransform x:Name="tt">
                                <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                                    <Matrix />
                                </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                            </MatrixTransform>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <Rectangle.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <MatrixAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:10" Storyboard.TargetName="tt" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix" AutoReverse="True" DoesRotateWithTangent="True" 
                                                             >
                                        <MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                            <PathGeometry Figures="M29.073618888855,0C29.1124091148376,1.1444091796875E-05 29.1515617370605,0.00176620483398438 29.1909990310669,0.00532913208007813 29.810998916626,0.0533294677734375 30.3119988441467,0.530315399169922 30.3919982910156,1.14829635620117L30.5836410522461,2.65130615234375 31.2817029953003,8.12605285644531 34.8569983541965,36.1663000583649 38.6119983196259,11.4410037994385C38.6989989280701,10.8670196533203 39.1539988517761,10.4180335998535 39.7279987335205,10.3390350341797 40.3039989471436,10.2600383758545 40.8659987449646,10.5700283050537 41.1039986610413,11.0990142822266L44.5239992141724,18.6847972869873 62.6889991760254,18.6847972869873C63.4129981994629,18.6847972869873 63.9999980926514,19.2727813720703 63.9999980926514,19.9957599639893 63.9999980926514,20.720739364624 63.4129981994629,21.3077239990234 62.6889991760254,21.3077239990234L43.6779985427856,21.3077239990234C43.1629986763,21.3077239990234,42.6949987411499,21.004732131958,42.4809985160828,20.5357456207275L40.5379986763,16.2248687744141 36.0409992933273,45.8410243988037C35.9439988136292,46.4820065498352,35.3929988443851,46.9559931755066,34.7459992468357,46.9559926986694L34.729998499155,46.9559926986694C34.0749988555908,46.9479932785034,33.5279988050461,46.4590072631836,33.4449987411499,45.8100252151489L28.5969982147217,7.7971076965332 19.7799987792969,38.5482323169708C19.6119985580444,39.1362158469856 19.0699996948242,39.5222048461437 18.4459991455078,39.4962055683136 17.8359985351563,39.4622065722942 17.3289985656738,39.0092194601893 17.2269992828369,38.4062369465828L13.6579990386963,17.2688388824463 10.7719993591309,23.3446655273438C10.5559997558594,23.8016519546509,10.0949993133545,24.0936441421509,9.58799934387207,24.0936441421509L1.31099700927734,24.0936441421509C0.587997436523438,24.0936441421509 0,23.5056610107422 0,22.7826805114746 0,22.0577011108398 0.587997436523438,21.4717178344727 1.31099700927734,21.4717178344727L8.75799942016602,21.4717178344727 13.0749988555908,12.3859767913818C13.3199996948242,11.8689918518066 13.8699989318848,11.57200050354 14.4389991760254,11.6499977111816 15.0059986114502,11.7299957275391 15.4579982757568,12.1669826507568 15.5519981384277,12.7309665679932L18.8509979248047,32.2744116783142 27.8319988250732,0.952301025390625C27.9913740158081,0.391693115234375,28.4917645454407,-0.000171661376953125,29.073618888855,0z">

                                            </PathGeometry>
                                        </MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                    </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Rectangle.Triggers>
                </Rectangle>
 </Canvas>
```

Edit 1:  my animation go wrong way . i want my Rectangle move exact Inside and in middle of path line . see code in your pc u will see the problem .
my question is how fix that problem ?

Edit 2: i change the animation with DoubleAnimationUsingPath same result

Edit 3 : [image]

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Any particular purpose for the MatrixAnimationUsingPath as opposed to [DoubleAnimationUsingPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that it interpolates between points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `Path` is actually a closed polygon not a line, therefore the `Rectangle` moves on the outline.

try this instead:

```
    <Canvas ClipToBounds="False" Width="400" Height="400">
        <Path StrokeThickness="8" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="Red">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 86,315 L 120,314 L 136,271 L 148,358 L 174,214 L 204,388 L 220,270 L 244,316 L 318,316" />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="4" Height="4" Margin="-2">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <MatrixTransform x:Name="tt">
                        <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                            <Matrix />
                        </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                    </MatrixTransform>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <MatrixAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:10" Storyboard.TargetName="tt" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix" AutoReverse="True" DoesRotateWithTangent="True" 
                                                         >
                                <MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 86,315 L 120,314 L 136,271 L 148,358 L 174,214 L 204,388 L 220,270 L 244,316 L 318,316">
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                            </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: Wow man thats exactly what i want but one more question can u help me how u convert my path data to this new data ? i want change other path data too . my path datas are polygon like .

Comment: download [this](https://xdraw.codeplex.com/) simple application, draw your path, then export it as a canvas.

Comment: i dont want draw i have some path data , some time hard to draw things i want convert path datas that i have (polygon like). is that application good for convert my data ?

Comment: you are welcome : ) you can also import your XAML as a drawing to the application for modification, but in your case, there are some string format issues that i have to toy with it a little.